# How do I add fade on document.createElement?

Tags: javascript, html, fadein, createelement

I am unsure of how to add a fade effect to the object created with document.createElement. I have tried
different methods with no result.

I am fairly new to JavaScript and could use some help. Does anyone have any 
solution for this?

Thanks in advance!

**HTML**

```
<fieldset>
<p id="drinkNameHeadline"> Drink Name </p>                          
<label for='drinkName'></label>
<input id="drinkName" type="name" name="drinkName">
<p id="ingredients"> Ingredients </p>

<label for='ingredient'></label>
<input id="textBar" type="name" name="ingredient">

<div id="textBarPosition"></div>
<input id="addBar" type="button" value="Add Ingredient Bar">    

<input class="submit" type="submit" value="Submit">                     
</fieldset>
```

**JavaScript**

```
function createSector() {
  var input = document.createElement('input'); input.setAttribute("id", 'textBar');
  input.type = 'text';
  input.name = 'name[]';
  return input;
}

var form = document.getElementById('textBarPosition');
document.getElementById('addBar').addEventListener('click', function(e) {
  form.appendChild(createSector());
});
```

Comment: What technique do you want to use for fading in the element: CSS3 transitions?  From scratch javascript?  jQuery animations?

Comment: Well jQuery is usually easier, I don't mind using that if there's a solution for it!

Comment: Please include the methods you tried for fading and show us what went wrong.

Comment: 1) append it with display:none or visibility:hidden then 2. fade it in with whatever method you have chosen

Comment: The code came from JSfiddle, http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/4M3Qv/ I am sure this works, but I am unsure of how to implement it correctly.

Comment: That's jQuery fadeIn method. The script would be simplified if you'd use jQuery.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To achieve a fade in effect, you have to add the element as child in 3 steps :

1. Set the opacity of your element to 0
2. Append it to the parent
3. do the animation of the opacity from 0 to 1 (the fade in effect)

In your code, something like that:

```js
document.getElementById('addBar').addEventListener('click', function(e) {
    // step 1: create element and set opacity to 0.
    var selector = createSelector();
    selector.style.opacity = 0; // be careful this is not working in IE before 9.

   // step 2: append it to its parent.
    form.appendChild(selector);

    // step 3: fade in (we choose to do 20 steps in 1 second to go from 0 to 1. Steps are 50ms each)
    var steps = 0;
    var timer = setInterval(function() {
        steps++;
        selector.style.opacity = 0.05 * steps;
        if(steps >= 20) {
            clearInterval(timer);
            timer = undefined;
        }
    }, 50);
});
```

If this code should work in IE 7 or 8 you have to add this line each time you set opacity:

```js
element.style.filter = "alpha(opacity=0)"; // for step 1
...
element.style.filter = "alpha(opacity=" + (5 * steps) + ")"; // for step 3
```

If you use jQuery your code can be simpler to write and you don't have to worry about IE compatibility for the opacity :

```js
document.getElementById('addBar').addEventListener('click', function(e) {
    // step 1: create element and set opacity to 0.
    var selector = $(createSelector());
    selector.css("opacity", 0);

   // step 2: append it to its parent.
    $(form).append(selector);

    // step 3: fade in
    selector.fadeIn();
});
```

Comment: Thank you so much for this! The JavaScript code worked perfectly!

Comment: It may be nicer to use css `transition: opacity 1s ease-in;` on 'addBar', than just change the opacity from 0 to 1.

Comment: Using transition is nice. This is just a matter of browser compatibility.

Comment: Yea, the jQuery code looks way more better with a smoother transition as well

Comment: For a smoother transition in plain javascript, you have to do a lot more than my sample code. With the use of **requestAnimationFrame** or a more complex sequence of **setTimeout** calls taking real time into account. If you can, let jQuery do this job for you :)

Comment: For even smoother transitions you shouldn't use JavaScript at all though.

Answer (score 4):

You don't need to do some JavaScript-calculations to create and fade in the element.
You should use css. Transition or animation.
The problem with transition in this example is that there needs to be some delay between the element is added to the DOM and when the fade in starts.
Here is an example with css animation.

```js
const divElement = document.createElement("div");
divElement.style.animation = "fade-in 3s";
document.body.appendChild(divElement);
```

```css
@keyframes fade-in {
  from { opacity: 0; }
  to { opacity: 1; }
}

div {
  width: 150px;
  height: 150px;
  background: black;
}
```

Comment: This is most elegant solution, without any additional dependencies like jQuery

Answer (score 0):

With relatively new browsers, you could use a [CSS animation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Using_CSS_animations) of the opacity property. But jQuery would make your live easier:

```
function createSector() {
  return $('<input>')
    .attr({id: 'textBar'})
    .prop({type: 'text', name: 'name[]'})
    .hide()
    .fadeIn();
}

var form = $('#textBarPosition');
$('#addBar').on('click', function(e) {
  form.appendChild(createSector());
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you do not mind to use jQuery (you should add tag), than you can use this:
**HTML**

```
<fieldset>

    <h3>Drink Name</h3>

    <p>
        <label for='drinkName'></label>
        <input id="drinkName" type="name" name="drinkName">
    </p>

    <h4>Ingredients</h4>

    <ol class="ingredients">
        <li>
            <label for="ingredient_0"></label>
            <input id="ingredient_0" type="name" name="ingredient[]">
        </li>
    </ol>

    <p>
        <input id="addBar" type="button" value="Add Ingredient Bar">
    </p>

    <p>
        <input class="submit" type="submit" value="Submit">
    </p>

</fieldset>
```

and than
**SCRIPT**

```
$(document).on('ready', function() {

    $('#addBar').on('click', function(e) {
        var ingredients = $('.ingredients');
        var totalIngredients = ingredients.find('li').length;
        var nextIngredient = $('\
            <li>\
                <label for="ingredient_' + totalIngredients + '"></label>\
                <input id="ingredient_' + totalIngredients + '" type="text" name="ingredient[]">\
            </li>');
        nextIngredient.hide().appendTo( ingredients ).fadeIn();
    });
});
```